# import JPA Model from gradle sub-project in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gradle, spring-boot

In an android project, I want to use a shared model library with the REST Server(JPA)
Project structure:

```
├── android
│   └ ...
│
├── model
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── com
│           └── model                            // error at runtime
│               └── Customer.java
├── server
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── com
│           └── server
│                ├── Application.java
│                ├── CustomerController.java
│                ├── CustomerRepository.java
│                └── model                       // works fine
│                    └── Customer.java
├── build.gradle
```

I am using gradle sub-projects to manage the dependency which works fine at compile time.
But when I run the Application, Spring can't resolve the JPA annotations.
When I move the model class to the server project, it works fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [...] Instantiation of bean failed;
[...] 
Not an managed type: class com.model.Customer
```

**root `build.gradle`**

```
buildscript {  ...  }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project(":android") {  ...  }

project(":model") {
    apply plugin: "java"
}

project(":server") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":model")
    }
}
```

**Is there a solution to include JPA models from a gradle sub-project ?**
The reason is mostly to prevent duplicate code between the android and server appication

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `Customer` entity will not be found by default because it is not in a sub-pacakge of your `Application` class. Try using the `@EntityScan` annotation (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration).